# Can I make iOS app paid in one country and free for rest of the world?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to limit download in one country to paid and non-paid in other countries. What's the solution?

Comment: This link will help u, check the [View or update local prices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en) to see how to select individual countries or check the box next to "Select all countries."

Comment: I was referring to Iphone apps not android apps is there a link for the it?

Comment: Sorry,... Have you checked [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html) yet? or [this](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/203122052-Create-an-Apple-App-Store-Paid-Applications-Contract)